# Why does awk print the whole line when I want it to print a variable?

Tags: awk, variable

When I type:

```
echo "foo bar" | gawk -v var="content" '{print $var}'
```

I expect the output to be `content`. Why is it `foo bar`?

Comment: Try removing `$` from $var

Comment: Indeed. I got confused with bash syntax...

Comment: It's a good question and though the answer shows that the `$` was misplaced I'm not sure it should be closed as typo. I've seen several of these recently so perhaps we need a canonical one

Comment: Didn't find this in time and created a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69829145/how-to-have-awk-print-variable-instead-of-the-full-matched-line/) by accident.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Variables are referenced by name as in `var`, not `$var` in `awk`. `$n` refers to the `n`<sup>th</sup> *field*: `$1` for the first field, `$2` for the second... or the whole record for `n` == 0 (`$0` is the full record).

Those don't have to be literal numbers. You can use `$(1+1)` or `$variable`. If `variable` contains `1`, then `$variable` will be the first field. A commonly used one is `$NF` for the last field (`NF` is the special variable that contains the number of fields).

If, like in your example, the variable doesn't contain a number, that *non-number* is understood as 0.

So `var="content"; print $var`, is the same as `var=0; print $var`, and thus the same as `print $0`, that is print the whole record.

What you want here is:

```
echo "foo bar" | gawk -v var="content" '{print var}'
```